# How to match a random length substring with _ excluded but empty character included in Regex?

Tags: regex

might be a noob question but really struggled with that. This is the context:

Say I have a string with the format `backend`. What I want to match is a string with `back` as prefix and `end` as suffix, between the `k` and `e` there could be any number of characters or even an empty character. Another limit is the next character of 'k' can not be `_` but `_` can appear in other places (the last matching example below).

Following are some matching examples:

`backend`, `back12345end`, `backSHITend`, `backSH_IT_end`

NO MATCH examples:

`back_end`, `back_sHiTend`, `back_cannotbe_end`

I was trying to use `back[^_]*end`, `back[^_].*end` but they both failed.

Any help would be appreciated a lot, thanks.

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/jmqfRI/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
back(?!_).*?end
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jmqfRI/1)

Comment: @Aurora: You're welcome. Be aware that accepted answer will not work if there are more than one `back...end` in a single line.

Comment: Ooops sorry I didn't get your point. Did you mean something like `back....back...end...end`?

Comment: @Aurora: Yes, or `back...end...back...end`

Comment: Oh I got you. Although that isn't what I need to worry about, thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

`back([^_].*)?end` should solve your problem. (? means zero or one match)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry my description was wrong: it should be "I was trying to use back[^_]*end, back[^_].*end but they both failed." But anyway your answer works!

Comment: no problem, I didn't even notice there were any mistakes.

Comment: Why do you use `payment`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I edited the answer to fix something else, must've made a slip while editting. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match whitespace chars between the words, you can optionally match a non whitespace char other than `_`, followed by optional non whitespace chars.

To prevent a partial match, you could use word boundaries `\b`.

```
\bback(?:[^\s_]\S*)?end\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7k9qE/1)

Or with a negative lookahead

```
\bback(?!_)\S*end\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amTsUf/1)